# Photoswipe and Require.js configuration

Tags: require, photoswipe

I have a module which is dependent upon both, PhotoSwipe and PhotoSwipeUI_Default. I am requiring both modules, like so and inside of my module I am initialising my gallery. EG:

```
define("modules/lightboxStart", ["vendor/PhotoSwipe", "vendor/PhotoSwipeUI_Default"], function (PhotoSwipe, PhotoSwipeUI_Default) {

   var StartGallery = function(){
      var lightBox =  new PhotoSwipe($pswp, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
            lightBox.init();
   }
   StartGallery()
}
```

The gallery then works as expected **but require is throwing a mismatched anonymous define module error in PhotoSwipe.js.**

After looking through the docs I came to the conclusion that I need to run both scripts(PhotoSwipe and PhotoSwipeUI_Default) through the require.js API.

I then defined each, like so:

```
define('PhotoSwipe', function() {
//PhotoSwipe script here
 return PhotoSwipe
 })
```

And

```
define('PhotoSwipeUI_Default', function() {
//PhotoSwipeUI_Default script here
 return PhotoSwipeUI_Default
 })
```

This then eliminates the mismatched anonymous define module error I was getting earlier, but I am getting this error now instead:

```
PhotoSwipe is not a function
```

How could I fix this? I am essentially trying to access the PhotoSwipe function within PhotoSwipe.js and pass through my arguments but I am unable to do so without generating a load of js errors on the page and I can not figure out why.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: You need to SHIM them and then use there dependancys

Comment: Shim the script which requires both PhotoSwipe dependencies and then list them as their dependencies in the shim? Or Shim the vendor scripts?

Answer (score -1):

define( ["modules/lightboxStart", "vendor/PhotoSwipe", "vendor/PhotoSwipeUI_Default"], function (lightboxStart, PhotoSwipe, PhotoSwipeUI_Default) { //i think so}

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.